# Attaching filter to raw sockets in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, setsockopt

That question is the next step of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595340/opening-raw-udp-socket-in-promiscuous-mode-c).

I changed my code to use AF_PACKET socket, but this time, my application needs to deal with lots of traffic. I decided to use LSF filter in order to decrease the workload of my application.

Here is my new program:

```
struct sock_fprog filter;
int i, lineCount = 0;
int sd;
char tcpdump_command[512];
FILE* tcpdump_output;
sprintf(tcpdump_command, "tcpdump \"udp && src %s && src port %d\" -ddd -s 1600", IP, PORT);
if ( (tcpdump_output = popen(tcpdump_command, "r")) == NULL ) {
    perror("Cannot compile filter using tcpdump.");
    return;
}
if ( fscanf(tcpdump_output, "%d\n", &lineCount) < 1 ) {
    printf("cannot read lineCount.\n");
    return;
}
filter.filter = calloc(sizeof(struct sock_filter)*lineCount,1);
filter.len = lineCount;
for ( i = 0; i < lineCount; i++ ) {
    if (fscanf(tcpdump_output, "%u %u %u %u\n", &(filter.filter[i].code), &(filter.filter[i].jt), &(filter.filter[i].jf), &(filter.filter[i].k)) < 4 ) {
        printf("error in reading line number: %d\n", (i+1));
        return;
    }
}
pclose(tcpdump_output);

sd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
if ( sd == -1 )
{
    perror("error in opening sd\n");
    return;
}

if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_PACKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, &filter, sizeof(filter)) < 0 )
{
    perror("Cannot attach filter");
    return -5;
}
```

The initialization of my socket seems correct according to [this](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/lind/os-Linux/drivers/rawsock_user.c). However, the final `setsockopt` fails with "protocol not available". Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use of `SOCK_RAW` requires specific permission; does your application run as a user that has this permission? If so, does your system also have permissions that go beyond user (such as application permission to finely controlled features)?

Comment: @mah I run this program as root. Besides, if I do not attach filter to my socket, I can receive packets (actually, lots of packets) from that socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SOL_SOCKET, from kernel doc [filter.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/filter.txt)

Ioctls-

```
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, &Filter, sizeof(Filter));
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DETACH_FILTER, &value, sizeof(value));
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LOCK_FILTER, &value, sizeof(value));
```

Comment: keep in mind that this doesn't filter packets which were received before you managed to call `setsockopt` so subsequent calls to `recv` [can still have packets which don't match the bpf](https://natanyellin.com/posts/ebpf-filtering-done-right/)